# Does Facebook multicast or unicast the live videos to its viewers?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, multicast, live-streaming, unicast

This is how a live stream goes from one broadcaster to millions of viewers:

1. A broadcaster starts a live video on their phone.
2. The phone sends a RTMP stream to a Live Stream server.
3. The Live Stream server decodes the video and transcodes to multiple bit rates.
4. For each bit rate a set of one-second MPEG-DASH segments is continuously produced.
5. Segments are stored in a datacenter cache.
6. From the datacenter cache segments are sent to caches located in the points of presence (a PoP cache).
7. On the view side the viewer receives a Live Story.
8. The player on their device starts fetching segments from a PoP cache at a rate of one per second.

My question is simple. After the step **6**, does **PoP cache/Edge cache/eNB** (*edge layer node*) multicast a live video content to multiple viewers or unicast each user separately (*opening up seperate streams for each user*)?

Comment: There is no multicast on the public internet.

Answer (score 0):

Unicast. Multicast doesn't work over the internet. Besides, DASH is done over HTTP and HTTP is done over TCP which you can't use with multicast anyway.